# Remove black border in pygame fullscreen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a game using pygame 1.9.6. But, as you can see by running this simple example, some black borders appear around the window, even with the `FULLSCREEN` flag.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500), FULLSCREEN)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I tried to add the flag `NOFRAME` in the screen initialisation, but it didn't work.

I wonder if it is possible to remove the border, for example by increasing the screen size to just fit in the current screen. But I also want to keep the `900x500` resolution.

Can `pygame` resize the entire screen? Do I have to `blit()` everything on a `Surface`, then rescale it and draw it on the actual screen?

Comment: If performance is an issue, you can try slowing down your game loop with `pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)`. For scaling, you still use full resolution mode, but you draw on a smaller surface and scale it when blitting to the main screen. Check this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/b8wwfr/stretching_a_game_screen_to_fit_fullscreen/

Comment: As you likely are aware, the black surrounding your window is because your screen is bigger than 900x500. Unless your screen dimensions are exactly a 9x5 ratio (mine is not), then even if you scale it to the size of the screen you are still going likely to get a bit of a black bar somewhere. That is unless your stretch it more in one dimension than the other, in which case you will no longer get round circles.

Comment: You could try using the `pygame.SCALED` flag along with FULLSCREEN in the `display.set_mode()` call. The docs describe it like this: `pygame.SCALED        resolution depends on desktop size and scale graphics`

Comment: Thanks Glenn Mackintosh! I updated my pygame version and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Glenn Mackintosh!

The best way to remove the black border is actually to add the `SCALED` flag in the screen declaration like this:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500), FULLSCREEN|SCALED)
```

But to use it, the pygame version `2.0.0` or more is required.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove the black bars is to set the `pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))` to the users resolution. Use `pygame.display.Info()` to get the users' display resolution. Furthermore, you can have a preferred resolution such as `900 x 500` to get a "differential number" to get a retro/pixelated look.

```py
resolution = pygame.display.Info()
width = resolution.current_w
height = resolution.current_h
dx = width // 900
dy = height // 500
```

This ***dx*** and ***dy*** can then be used to scale everything to a bigger size.

I would try this code:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init() # You forgot the initialize the pygame window!
resolution = pygame.display.Info() # Get the users resolution
width = resolution.current_w
height = resolution.current_h
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), FULLSCREEN, 0, 32)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), mouse_pos, 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 200), mouse_pos, 18)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 100), mouse_pos, 15)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 50), mouse_pos, 10)

    pygame.display.flip()
```